# After Generating a Listing Template, When we place the template in eBay - We can see unnecessary New Line - how to resolve via java-script?

Tags: javascript, php, html

After Generating a Listing Template, When we place the template in eBay - We can see unnecessary New Line.

```
 copy_template.addEventListener('click', function() {

        generated_code.value = document.head.innerHTML; 
        generated_code.value += wrapper.innerHTML;
        generated_code.select();

        if( document.execCommand('copy') ) {
          copy_template.style.backgroundColor = '#a5d6a7';
          console.log('Copied to Clipboard!');
        }
```

Comment: Can you supply an example document so we can see what `generated_code.value` will be. Also can you give an example of what you mean by "New Line"

Comment: https://www.ecomclips.com/ebay/app/

when i generated code and copy the code we can see extra space in inner Html.when we put inner html with extra space then it doesn't showing properly.

Comment: You're still not giving an example of the problem, send a screen shot of exactly what you are seeing and what the state of the innerHTML is at that point.

Comment: when we generated code and copy the code showing extra space.
https://prnt.sc/n51r09

Comment: You're drip feeding details for some reason so it is hard to offer any advice, can I suggest that you update the question with that screen shot as well as more information about the variable contents when you are doing all this.